# Get checksum from file larger than available memory

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdata, checksum

I'm building an application, where I need to find the checksum from a file.

So far I've successfully been able to get the checksum by loading the file into a NSData object, and using the following piece of code:

```
@implementation NSData (Checksums)
    - (NSString*)md5 {
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( self.bytes, (int)self.length, result );
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];  
    }
@end
```

However when I'm trying to get the checksum from a file that is larger than my available memory (eg. 8GB RAM and 20GB file), this solution doesn't work because I can't load the entire file into the object.

Is there a way I can get the checksum from a file, without loading the file into a NSData object?

Answer (score 0):

You habe to use the functions `CC_MD5_Init`, `CC_MD5_Update`, and `CC_MD5_Final`. You call `CC_MD5_Init` once and then pass chunks of the data to `CC_MD5_Update` until you're done with the file. Then call `CC_MD5_Final` to get the MD5 checksum for the file.

For reading the file in parts use `[NSFileHandle readDataOfLength:]`.

If you want a lazy solution you can also use `NSTask` to run the command line tool `md5`.